# Why does deleting a line in sed use memory?

Tags: memory, sed

I have a 1.5GB GNU zipped text file from which I want to delete one (syntactically invalid) line.  I'm using the following command for this:

```
zcat foo.gz | sed -n '36690930d' | gzip > bar.gz
```

The above results in Sed using all the memory on my machine, and getting killed by the OS.

Why does Sed use any noticeable amount of memory at all (TWISI it should just stream through the file and skip one line somewhere, no memory needed)?

And what would be a better way to achieve line deletion using no/little memory?

Comment: Are you sure it's sed? when you remove it from the pipeline, does it remove the problem?

Comment: That command will surely remove **all** lines as you use `-n`

Comment: @MarkSetchell, I've just read your profile info. Thank you for the _barrel of laughs_! (I hope those three words mean what I think they mean.) Besides, would `-n` explain the use of memory? If so, then this question should be closed because a typo generated the problem.

Comment: Can you try using a tmp file on a partition with a lot of space (other than the one where foo.gz and bar.gz are located) ? Use `sed` without the option `-n` or something like `zgrep -v '36690930' foo.gz > "${mytmpfile}" && gzip "${mytmpfile}" > bar.gz && rm "${mytmpfile}"`

Comment: Not sure which `sed` you are using, but do you have an *"unbuffered"*, or a *"line-buffered"* switch available, e.g. `sed -u` ?